# Deploying Eureka server and clients on Railway and cannot reach server from client anymore

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka, railway

I am using 2 server: Client with Vaadin 24 and spring boot 3.1.2 and Server with Spring boot 3.1.2
I add the Eureka server and make my servers as a Eureka Client and localy it worked fine, but when I deploy all my services within a Eureka Server and trying to reach server from client I have this error:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fg6N2.png)
[More desc.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5fvZ.png)

[Here is my Client application.properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEk3N.png)

[Here is my Server application.properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lT7bo.png)

[Here is deployed Eureka server and my Eureka-clients](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bL8BX.png)

[Here is @LoadBalancer WebClient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OPtt.png)

When I use direct link to server everything works. I dont think there is some problem with configuration or something, I currently thinking about routing error or Railway just block this. Thanks for any help, hope to solve it